# Generating a plot for all the time steps of netcdf file into a map

Tags: python, plot, netcdf

I was wondering if it's possible to plot all the steps from this single netcdf file into a separate plots.

Step 113 means that the current accessed data is for the date of October 22,2019. The Step 0 is July 1,2019. There are 135 time steps overall. Which means I need to produce 135 maps for each and single day.

```
#x,y,u,v for the maps
X=Data.longitude; Y=Data.latitude;
U=Data.u10[113]; V=Data.v10[113];
pm2p5=Data.pm2p5[113];
```

This is my code so far.

```
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy import feature as cf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm


Data=xr.open_dataset('PMs ECMWF2.nc')

#x,y,u,v for the maps
X=Data.longitude; Y=Data.latitude;
U=Data.u10[113]; V=Data.v10[113];
pm2p5=Data.pm2p5[113];


nlon, nlat = np.meshgrid(X,Y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=300)

# Add Plotting the plot
ax=plt.subplot(111,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Add Plot features
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, linewidth=.5, edgecolor="yellow")
ax.coastlines('50m', linewidth=0.8)
ax.add_feature(cf.LAKES)
ax.add_feature(cf.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, edgecolor="yellow")
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, edgecolor="yellow")
ax.add_feature(cf.RIVERS)
ax.gridlines()

#changing the location of the map
ax.set_extent([90, 141, 24, -10])

# Add gridlines, and set their font size
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1, color='black', alpha=0.05, linestyle='-')
gl.top_labels = False
gl.left_labels = True
gl.right_labels = False
gl.xlines = True
gl.ylines = True

#colorbar
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # Colour map coolwarm,hsv,bwr, seismic

# plotting the variables
pm2p5.plot(transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.5}, cmap=cmap)
plt.contour(nlon, nlat, pm2p5, fontsize=10,cmap=cmap) #plotting the contours


#plotting the quiver
ax.quiver(X[::3],Y[::3],U[::3,::3],V[::3,::3], color='white')


#plot title 
#plt.title('Carbon Monoxide on October 22, 2019')

plt.show()
```

As of right now this code only produce one image. I have to do this over and over again.
[image]

Comment: You should make a loop over time and for each time moment produce a map.

Comment: @msi_gerva Hello! yes that was my plan but i cant seem to find any guide as to how to make a loop for that since most of the for loop instructions I saw were for different file not for a single file. If its okay can you help me create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example of making a loop over time variable and maps of variable inside the loop, is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------------
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date
# ---------------------------
# let us generate data, preferably to the netcdf:
nx=50;ny=50;ntime=10;
A=np.random.random((ntime,ny,nx));
lon = np.linspace(0,360,nx);
lat = np.linspace(-90,90,ny);
time = np.linspace(0,366,ntime);timeunit = 'days since 2020-01-01 00:00:00'
fout = 'test.nc'
with Dataset(fout,'w') as f:
    f.createDimension('longitude',nx);
    f.createDimension('latitude',ny);
    f.createDimension('time',);
    xv = f.createVariable('longitude','float32',('longitude'));xv[:]=lon
    yv = f.createVariable('latitude','float32',('latitude'));yv[:]=lat;
    tv = f.createVariable('time','float32',('time'));tv[:]=time;tv.setncattr('units',timeunit);
    u10 = f.createVariable('u10','float32',('time','latitude','longitude'));u10[:]=A;
    v10 = f.createVariable('v10','float32',('time','latitude','longitude'));v10[:]=-A;
    pm2 = f.createVariable('pm2p5','float32',('time','latitude','longitude'));pm2[:]=A;
    
# -----------------------------------------------
# let us now make some maps:
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy import feature as cf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm


Data=xr.open_dataset(fout)

#x,y,u,v for the maps
X=Data.longitude; Y=Data.latitude;

time = Data.time;

for itime in range(len(time)):
    U=Data.u10[itime]; V=Data.v10[itime];
    pm2p5=Data.pm2p5[itime];

    nlon, nlat = np.meshgrid(X,Y)


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=300)

    # Add Plotting the plot
    ax=plt.subplot(111,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    # Add Plot features
    ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, linewidth=.5, edgecolor="yellow")
    ax.coastlines('50m', linewidth=0.8)
    ax.add_feature(cf.LAKES)
    ax.add_feature(cf.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, edgecolor="yellow")
    ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, edgecolor="yellow")
    ax.add_feature(cf.RIVERS)
    ax.gridlines()

    #changing the location of the map
    ax.set_extent([90, 141, 24, -10])

    # Add gridlines, and set their font size
    gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1, color='black', alpha=0.05, linestyle='-')
    gl.top_labels = False
    gl.left_labels = True
    gl.right_labels = False
    gl.xlines = True
    gl.ylines = True

    #colorbar
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # Colour map coolwarm,hsv,bwr, seismic

    # plotting the variables
    pm2p5.plot(transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.5}, cmap=cmap)
    plt.contour(nlon, nlat, pm2p5, fontsize=10,cmap=cmap) #plotting the contours


    #plotting the quiver
    ax.quiver(X[::3],Y[::3],U[::3,::3],V[::3,::3], color='white')


   #plot title 
   #plt.title('Carbon Monoxide on October 22, 2019')
    plt.savefig('fig_'+str(itime).rjust(3,'0')+'.png',bbox_inches='tight');
    plt.show();
    # ----------------------------
```

I first generated a netCDF with random values and then plotted the variables for each time moment.

Comment: Oh!!! Thank you very much! This would help me a lot. I'll give this one a try!

Comment: You're welcome! I hope the script works as an example how to make a plot over different timesteps.

Comment: Yup i have managed to see the output for the script that you have made however, an error occurred when I used it on my file. "ValueError: unable to decode time units 'days since 2020-01-01 00:00:00' with 'the default calendar'. Try opening your dataset with decode_times=False or installing cftime if it is not installed."

Comment: **UPDATE:** It did work! I just have to place the decode_times on here `Data=xr.open_dataset(fout, decode_times=False)`. thank you very much!!